# Why Do We Need Maybe Monad Over Either Monad

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, option-type, either

I was playing around Maybe and Either monad types (Chaining, applying conditional functions according to returned value, also returning error message which chained function has failed etc.). So it seemes to me like we can achieve same and more things that Maybe does by using Either monad. So my question is where the practical or conceptual difference between those ?

Comment: I'm stunned this isn't a dupe. Great question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are of course right that `Maybe a` is isomorphic to `Either Unit a`. The thing is that they are often semantically used to denote different things, a bit like the difference between returning `null` and throwing a `NoSuchElementException`:

- `Nothing`/`None` denotes the "expected" missing of something, while
- `Left e` denotes an error in getting it, for whatever reason.

That said, we might even combine the two to something like:

```
query :: Either DBError (Maybe String)
```

where we express both the possibility of a missing value (a DB `NULL`) and an error in the connection, the DBMS, or whatever (not saying that there aren't better designs, but you get the point).

Sometimes, the border is fluid; for `saveHead :: [a] -> Maybe a`, we could say that the expected possibility of the error is encoded in the intent of the function, while something like `saveDivide` might be encoded as `Float -> Float -> Either FPError Float` or `Float -> Float -> Maybe Float`, depending on the use case (again, just some stupid examples...).

If in doubt, the best option is probably to use a custom result ADT with semantic encoding (like `data QueryResult = Success String | Null | Failure DBError`), and to prefer `Maybe` to simple cases where it is "traditionally expected" (a subjective point, which however will be mostly OK if you gain experience).

Answer (score 18):

@phg's answer is great. I will chime in with something that helped clear it up for me when I was learning them:

- `Maybe` is one (value) or none – ie, you have a value or you have nothing
- `Either` is a logical disjunction, but you always have at least one (value) - ie, you have one *or* the other, but not both.

`Maybe` is great for things like where you may or may not have a value - for example looking for an item in a list. if the list contains it, we get `(Just x)` otherwise we get `Nothing`

`Either` is the perfect representation of a branch in your code - it's going to go one way or the other; `Left` or `Right`. We use a mnemonic to remember it: `Right` is the *right* (*correct*) way; `Left` is the *wrong* way (Error). This is not it's only use of course, but definitely the most common.

I know the differences might seem subtle at first, but really they're suitable for very different things.

Comment: For mentioning logical disjunction you get the + 1. This is *very* approachable answer for someone new to FP.

Comment: Thanks Jared. Your feedback means a lot to me ^_^

Comment: "for example looking for an item in a list" I think this example makes it even harder to really understand the difference? That still looks like Either. You either get an element or nothing

Comment: @Farid no, Either means **either value A or value B**. Maybe means **maybe a value or no value at all**.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you see, we can put this to the extreme by saying that all product types can be represented by just 2-tuples and all non-recursive sum types by `Either`. To additionally represent recursive types, we need a fixpoint type.

For example, why have 4-tuples `(a,b,c,d)` when we could as well write `(a, (b, (c,d)))` or `(((a,b), c), d)` ?

Or why have lists, when the following works as well?

```
data Y f = Y (f (Y f))

type List a = Y ((,) (Either () a))


nil = Y (Left (), undefined)

cons a as = Y (Right a, as)

infixr 4 cons

numbers = 1 `cons` 2 `cons` 3 `cons` nil

-- this is like foldl

reduce f z (Y (Left (), _)) = z
reduce f z (Y (Right x, xs)) = reduce f (f z x) xs


total = reduce (+) 0 numbers
```